# Convert string to object array

Tags: javascript

I want to convert string to object array. Suppose I have following string.

```
const str = "someValue,display";
```

I want to convert it like following.

```
[{
  columnVal: "someValue",
  display: true
}]
```

if it's **display** then I want value as true if noDisplay then false.

I tried following but, doesn't seems like best solution.

```js
const val = "someValue,display";
const obj = {};

val.split(",").forEach((str, index) => {
    if(index === 0) {
        obj.columnVal = str;
  } else {
    if(str == "display") {
        obj.display = true;
    } else {
        obj.display = false;
    }
  }
})
console.log([obj]);
```

Comment: What is wrong with this solution? The only thing I could think of would be to either merge the `else if`, or to use `obj.display = str === "display"`. Note that code review questions should go on [codereview.se].

Comment: you want make shorter code ?

Comment: Is there always a second element in the string?

Comment: you can completely avoid the inner if else statement by `obj.display=str === "display";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a loop when you want to do something with specific indexes seems wrong. Just access the elements you want and set the appropriate object properties.

```js
const val = "someValue,display";
const vals = val.split(",");
const obj = {
  columnVal: vals[0],
  display: vals[1] == "display"
};

console.log([obj]);
```

Comment: Even more compact would be destructuring: `const [ columnVal, display ] = val.split(",");`, `{ columnVal, display: display === "display" }`.

Comment: ^^^ I'd prefer this solution over mine, you'd just need to assign the object to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically there, you just don't need to loop through it.

```
const obj = {}

const strArr = str.split(",")

obj.display = strArr.includes("display")
obj.columnVal = strArr[0]  // as long as this never changes
```

Answer (score 0):

you dont need loop on it, I think this is more effective way

```js
const str = "someValue,display",obj = {};
arr = str.split(",");
obj.columnVal = arr[0]; 
obj.display = arr === "display";
console.log([obj]);
```